# Sinch Managed Push not working for some mobile devices (Android)

Tags: sinch

mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext()).userId(username)
                .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
                .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

```
    mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
    mSinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);

    mSinchClient.checkManifest();
    //mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();

    mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
    mSinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener();
```

The code is implemented to sense incoming calls using sinch, and it works well on some mobiles. But there are also devices where the incoming call is not sensed. The GCM receiver though receives the call when the app is ON, but the incoming call method is not called.

Please suggest how to tackle this issue. My device has android 4.4.4 version. Is it version dependent?

Comment: do you have the GCM reciever as a service in your app so it lives even if the app is killed

Comment: and you ave you set up all GCM ids and stuff, one way to make sure is to not listen to active connection at all then its always push

Comment: Yeah I have implemented the GCM receiver as obtained from your sample application and all are managed push. But incoming calls though sensed by the GCM receiver the incoming method is not called in some devices.